# Move an item in array to first position from last position in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this

```js
var column = ["generic complaint", "epidemic complaint", "epidemic1 complaint", "epidemic2 complaint", "bal vivah", "name"]
```

I want the Last array element to be placed in first position , the sorted array should like this

```js
var column = ["name","generic complaint", "epidemic complaint", "epidemic1 complaint", "epidemic2 complaint", "bal vivah"]
```

need the solution in typescript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
let last = column.pop();
column.unshift(last);
```

Pop is used to remove the last variable but you can assign it.
Unshift will add a new item at the start of an array.

Comment: You can also combine those 2 functions: `columns.unshift(columns.pop())`